# Suppose $u,v$ in $V$. Prove that $<u,v> = 0$ iff $||u||$ is at most $||u+av||$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Claim: Suppose $u,v$ 
∈

V. Then $<u,v>$ $=$ $0$ iff $||u|| $
≤
 $||u+av||$ 
∀
$a$
∈
$F$

Proof. (
⟹) Suppose $<u,v>$ $=$ $0$. By properties of the inner product we have that 
∀
$a$
∈
$F$ $<u,av>$ $=$ conjugate of a $<u,v>$. So $<u,av>$ $=$ $0$ since $<u,v>$ $=$ $0$. Now since 

$u$
⊥ $av$ 
⟹ $||u||^2$ $+$ $||av||^2$ $=$ $||u+av||^2$ by the Pythagorean Theorem. Thus $||u||^2$ 
≤
 $||u+av||^2$ 
⟹ $||u||$ 
≤ $||u+av||$ as claimed.

I'm stuck on the second part of the proof where I have to prove the other direction.